# difference between HttpContext.Session and HttpContext.Application

Tags: model-view-controller

In C#, MVC 4, 
What's the difference between HttpContext.Session and HttpContext.Application?
What are the consideration of choosing between them and their usage?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't related to C#, MVC 4 but to web development in general.

**Session Context** : If you want data to persist multiple page requests but possibly for a limited time for a browser "session" - you'd use session context. E.g Login a user to his bank account.

**Application Context** : If you want data to persist multiple browser sessions regardless of what one or more user does in his/her session. E.g. Hit Counter of your application.